# Extract a string 6 letters and 6 numbers and append to end each line

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have a text file with random garbled text. Amongst the text are unique strings of 6 letters and 6 numbers, like this:

```
sdfdso3jmvdsoo30)(dfds^dsf sd ;;s dfds;QWERTY123456d fdsfdsf4544;
sadk321143)S3244@#((#@4^^^   fdsfgdsf324; er4; ABCDEF123456dsfdsdsfd
```

I need to extract the string and append it to the end of the line, like the two lines below:

> sdfdso3jmvdsoo30)(dfds^dsf sd ;;s dfds;QWERTY123456d fdsfdsf4544;
>   QWERTY123456 sadk321143)S3244@#((#@4^^^   fdsfgdsf324; er4;
>   ABCDEF123456dsfdsdsfd ABCDEF123456

I've asked around and know I need to have a `sed` command match the regex of `([A-Z]{6}[0-9]{6})` but I'm not proficient enough to work it out otherwise.

Comment: Does this post differ from this one (posted some hour ago)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455325/script-to-find-random-string-of-6-letters-6-numbers-and-append-it-to-the-end-of

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -r 's/(.*)([a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{6})(.*)/& \2/' file 
sdfdso3jmvdsoo30)(dfds^dsf sd ;;s dfds;QWERTY123456d fdsfdsf4544; QWERTY123456
sadk321143)S3244@#((#@4^^^   fdsfgdsf324; er4; ABCDEF123456dsfdsdsfd ABCDEF123456
```

*Note: if you're only interesting in uppercase letters replace `[a-zA-Z]` with just `[A-Z]`*.

Comment: A little simpler: `sed -r 's/^.*([a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{6}).*$/& \1/' file `

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sed 's/^\(.*\)\([A-Z]\{6\}[0-9]\{6\}\)\(.*\)$/\1\2\3 \2/' infile
```

It yields:

```
sdfdso3jmvdsoo30)(dfds^dsf sd ;;s dfds;QWERTY123456d fdsfdsf4544; QWERTY123456
sadk321143)S3244@#((#@4^^^   fdsfgdsf324; er4; ABCDEF123456dsfdsdsfd ABCDEF123456
```

---

**UPDATE**: Just for fun and to add something different, here a `pawk` version. It's the `python` version of `awk`:

```
pawk --import re -s 's = re.search(r"[A-Z]{6}\d{6}", l).group(); print l, s' <infile
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `gnu awk`

```
awk  '{a=gensub(/.*([[:upper:]][[:upper:]][[:upper:]][[:upper:]][[:upper:]][[:upper:]][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]).*/,"\\1",$0);print $0,a}' file
sdfdso3jmvdsoo30)(dfds^dsf sd ;;s dfds;QWERTY123456d fdsfdsf4544; QWERTY123456
sadk321143)S3244@#((#@4^^^   fdsfgdsf324; er4; ABCDEF123456dsfdsdsfd ABCDEF123456
```